# What is the macro formula for copy data sheets from monthly name file?

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry my English not very good, also still newbie in macro.

I'm able to formula grabbing data doing copy paste other sheets on other files. but the problem is the files is on monthly and year.. So i need to change the macro formula every year.

Example:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"C:\REPORT\2016\february\STOCK REPORT_JANUARI_*2016*.xls"
```

Is there any formula or something so i didn't need to change the year every times?

Comment: @A.S.H that's harsh, I modifed just a little, wanted to leave his post as much as possible :)

Comment: @A.S.H if i need to correct it just tell me the correct one, English isn't main language for me and i still learning so sorry if the question is so poor in grammar LOL

Comment: @MikoIndra No offense meant, just putting a little good mood into it :) The question is clear enough and that's why you got the perfect answer ;). My joke was addressed to Shai btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Year` Function.

Using `Year(Date)` equals the year of the currebt date. For today, `Year("28/02/2017")` equals 2017.

Replace your line of code with the line below:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"C:\REPORT\2016\february\STOCK REPORT_JANUARI_*" & Year(Date) & "*.xls"
```

Comment: nope is not working...............wait it's working but i deleted * from it

Comment: @MikoIndra are you getting an error ? when running in "Debug" what is the value you are getting for `Year("Whatever Date you had here")` ?

Comment: How about if the file name like this "C:\REPORT\2016\february\STOCK REPORT_1_2_" & Year(Date) & ".xls"..........how about the month so the only change will be the date only?

Comment: debug error show me the file name ......*2017* so i delete it and using only " & Year(Date) & " done it's working the next question about how about month what function i must use?

Comment: @MikoIndra you shuld open a new post, add your updated edited code, and ask what you want to achieve. It will allow other users (besides me) helping you

Comment: do i need to use month function? for the month?

Comment: thanks...still newbie need a lot to learn i appreciate your help and the valuable information.